# Select distinct where any of the filters are true

Tags: t-sql

Hello how do you select distinct rows when any of the filters return true?
Here is my Statement but it is returning a Cartesian result set of many thousands of duplicate rows. I don't want duplicate rows.

```
SELECT 
Distinct
  r.DRAWING
, r.[DESC]
, r.CF3 as rCF3
, e.OP_PSI    

From  thk t
left join eng e on e.DRAWING = t.DRAWING
left join ref r on r.DRAWING = t.DRAWING
where t.SurveyNumber = @SurveyNumber
or CAST(e.L_RATE AS DECIMAL(10,0)) >= 14
or CAST(e.S_RATE AS DECIMAL(10,0)) >= 14
or (YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(e.REPLDATE)) <= 2
or CAST(e.WALL_LOSS AS DECIMAL(10,2)) >= .30
or CAST(e.RMS AS DECIMAL(10,0)) <= 25
or t.CF1 = 'AI'
ORDER BY r.DRAWING;
```

Comment: You need to use `or`

Comment: I Seriously doubt it returns a Cartesian result. Your where condition practically turns the left join with `eng` to an inner join, for one thing. You probably have multiple records on `eng` and `ref` where the `Drawing` column is equal to a single record on `thk`, perhaps to multiple records. Anyway, without seeing sample data (DDL + DML, **Please**), desired results and current result, it's going to be very hard to give an exact answer. Please [edit] your question to include this.